# how to read multiline output command line by line, in a shell script?

Tags: shell, multiline

If I execute the command `android list avd` I got the following output

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: X10_Mini
    Path: /home/myhome/.android/avd/X10_Mini.avd
  Target: Android 2.1 (API level 7)
     ABI: armeabi
    Skin: 240x320
  Sdcard: 2G
---------
    Name: AVD_for_4in_WVGA_Nexus_S
    Path: /home/myhome/.android/avd/AVD_for_4in_WVGA_Nexus_S.avd
  Target: Android 2.1 (API level 7)
     ABI: armeabi
    Skin: 480x800
  Sdcard: 2G
```

and I'd like to store Name and target in arrays in a shell script
If I use the command

```
for elem in `android list avd | cut -d: -f1,2`; do
    echo $elem;
done;
```

the variable $elem will (obviously) contain each word of the whole output.

How can I read the output of the command line per line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I found a different solution, where I can use variables also outside the loop
I have to change the default IFS to newline

```
echo Searching for android virtual devices ...
IFS=$'\n';
for l in $(${PROGDIR}/android list avd) ; do
   VAR1=$(echo $l | cut -d: -f1 | sed -e 's/\s*//'); #sed removes trailing blanks
   if [ $VAR1 == "Name" ]; then
      NUM_AVD=$(($NUM_AVD+1));
   fi;
done
echo "NUM_AVD=$NUM_AVD"
```

In this case NUM_AVD is correctly 2